# Enable Opposite

Tags: qt, double-click

Why won't this work?

```
void RatingWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    this->setEnabled(!this->Enabled);
}
 // I also tried...
void RatingWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
if(this->isEnabled())
    this->setEnabled(false);
else
    this->setEnabled true;
}
```

It works the first time, but after that it remains disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the documentation..

> An enabled widget handles keyboard and mouse events; a disabled widget
>   does not.

So once you disable it, you aren't going to get any more mouse events :)